# Failed to compile - Module not found when installing Formik library for React

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm having installation issues with Formik.

Using my node.js cmd prompt, I am able to install a React project successfully.

I then follow [this guide](https://formik.org/docs/tutorial) where I install Formik and delete all files in the "src" folder of where I created my React project and replaced/added them with two files which are the [style.css](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-v2-tutorial-start-s04yr?file=/src/styles.css:0-13160) and [index.js](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-v2-tutorial-start-s04yr?file=/src/index.js:0-759) files to the "src" folder.

But whenever I initiate the project after adding both those files and installing Formik, I get this issue:

```
Failed to compile
./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './styles.css' in 'C:\Users\*Name*\my-app\src'
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

I tried deleting my package-lock.json file, reinstalling my packages and the Formik library but none of them are working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In CodeSandbox everything works fine, but in the question you mentioned `style.css` in sandbox your css filename is `styles.css` and you are importing it like `import "./styles.css";`. So i am guessing maybe you named your css file like `style.css` in your app. And in `index.js` when you try to import a css file with the name `styles.css` it gives an error